# Как конвертировать clock_t в int

Tags: c++, c, время

Как конвертировать clock_t в int? Мне нужно сделать это с точностью до системных тиков.

Comment: Почему бы вам в таком случае не использовать функцию time()? Порылся немного в Интернете - ничего не нашел подходящего. Если вам надо лишь выводить на экран это число, то используйте функцию printf с форматированием. если гуру языка си не найдут ничего подходящего. Вот здесь есть пример использования функции clock() и типа clock_t: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/

Comment: Мне нужно ограничивать fpc. Есть ли какая-та артельнатива?

Comment: фпс это количество кадров в секунду, а значит, нужно измерять обычное время, скажем, сколько кадров в секунду произошло, и убирать лишние кадры, т.е. обычную секунду делить на количества кадров и отталкиватся от этого. Я думаю процессорное время не подойдет. Вот здесь пытались решить проблему, похожую на вашу http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483974/converting-time-t-to-int . Я думаю, если вы хотите мерять фпс, то вам надо каким-то образом добывать это из драйвера видеокарты.

Comment: Я думаю, все гораздо проще. Выводим кадр, смотрим, сколько времени прошло. Если меньше 1/30 секунды, то ждем. Если больше - выводим второй кадр немедленно. В любом случае, после второго кадра опять проверяем, прошло меньше или больше 2/30 секунды. Вот еще посмотри - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BogoMIPS

Comment: @VadimTukaev я так и сказал: а ожидание это и есть отброс лишних кадров. все зависит от того какое он приложении пишит. например если сообщения для перерисовки приходят в само приложение виндовс то можно удалять сообщение из общей очереди. а если это движок игры? то прийдется смотреть в сторону видео драйвера, я думаю там уже реализовано все остается пользоватся этим функционалом (типа библиотечной функции какие нибудь GetFps SetFps).

Comment: > а если это движок игры? 

Угадали)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если с точностью до секунд, то так:

```
(int)(clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Comment: Мне нужно с точностью до системных тиков